# Error with Duplicate Primary key in Marketing Cloud SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sqlserver

We have multiple newsletters that generate leads for marketing emails. I'm trying to automate the process of consolidating those leads into one master data extension after they have been on a newsletter list for 30 days.

Currently, the sql I'm using looks like this:

```
SELECT 
           L.CreatedDate
          ,L.EmailAddress
          ,L.ListID
          ,L.Status
FROM ent._ListSubscribers L
where l.ListID   in  (20798913, 20757098, 20828774, 20233021, 20551644, 18973750, 20549665, 20540177, 20712964, 20233025, 19009581, 19009580, 20427611, 19649300, 20233035, 20585536, 20468748, 19009576, 19009574, 19009571, 19009570) /*All_Pub_Lists*/
and
Status   =  'Active'
and
CreatedDate between (dateAdd(dd, -31, dateAdd(dd, 0, getDate()))) and (dateAdd(dd, -30, dateAdd(dd, 0, getDate())))
and
l.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from ent.Master_Prospect_Copy)
```

The query activity is set to append new data in the target data extension. I was able to run the query a single time and it produced the expected results. However, now whenever the query activity runs it fails due to a Duplicate Primary Key error.

The error makes sense, as people are free to sign up to newsletters whenever they'd like, so they end up on multiple lists with multiple created dates. I tried to removed the duplicates with the

```
and
l.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from ent.Master_Prospect_Copy)
```

but it hasn't worked.

Does anyone know how I might continue to append new data, but avoid triggering the Duplicate Primary Key error?

Best,
Jeff

Comment: Is email address your primary key?

Comment: You would need a sub query that collects all the contacts,  a row number over by partition to group them and an additional WHERE condition to for where Row > 1

Comment: Email address is my primary key, apologies for not specifying. I'll give your suggestion a shot, thanks!

Comment: No need for the sub query

Comment: Hi did this work for you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I'm having some trouble on my end implementing your suggestion. With the alias, I was getting an invalid column name error for Row. When I removed it, I still got the duplicate key error. I'm pretty sure the issue on my end. I'm relatively new to sql.

Comment: Have you created a date extension in your de called Row?

Comment: Hi JEff..how are you getting along? Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not following up sooner. I've been on vacation. Our data team ended up creating a new master data extension for us that includes an "Earliest List Join Date" field. So I was able to just query that instead.

Comment: But thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Because you are only interested in distinct leads I would use this:


SELECT 
           Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY EmailAddress ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS Row
           ,L.CreatedDate
          ,L.EmailAddress
          ,L.ListID
          ,L.Status
FROM ent._ListSubscribers L
where l.ListID   in  (20798913, 20757098, 20828774, 20233021, 20551644, 18973750, 20549665, 20540177, 20712964, 20233025, 19009581, 19009580, 20427611, 19649300, 20233035, 20585536, 20468748, 19009576, 19009574, 19009571, 19009570) /*All_Pub_Lists*/
and
Status   =  'Active'
and
CreatedDate between (dateAdd(dd, -31, dateAdd(dd, 0, getDate()))) and (dateAdd(dd, -30, dateAdd(dd, 0, getDate())))
and
Row = 1
```

Should solve it

Comment: Sorry about the formatting can't get it write on my phone

Comment: Also you don't need the aliases